# How can I fix this sagging frame on a wooden shed?

Tags: wood, framing, shed

Right now there are a couple of vertical 2x4s holding up the frame. I'm wondering how I can fix this without tearing it out and starting over. Not sure how safe this is right now.

[image: wooden shed]

Comment: Add more supports.  A 2x4 beam can only span a short amount without needing support, a wall or posts(4x4s).   Were blocks removed from the top of the wall?

Comment: That short little stub of 2x4 sitting on the CMU wall? It seems like it should be out of plane from the 4x4 and the other 2x4.  Does it just have a thin little strip of bearing on top of the wall?

Comment: Looks like increasing support as @crip659 suggested should help. At least that left vertical 2x4 should be able to have a couple more 2x4s sistered in from the left.

Comment: A bearing wall with studs centered under the rafters is probably easiest. You could space the studs on 24" centers if you do a double top plate. Depending on the foundation at the bottom, you might build it just to the inside of the current stuff, demolish the post(s) and 2x4s, and then sledge the wall into position.

Comment: Are there any sheathed walls to provide stability against toppling? Or is it just leaning against the CMU walls for stability?

Comment: So here you appear to have a 4x4 corner post, a 4x4 top plate, and two 2x4s of dubious bearing  on the to plate. How long is the wall, what's supporting the other end, what is your roof loading?

Comment: Please provide closeup photos of the studs meeting teh beam